# While loop condition php

Tags: php, while-loop

Why does not the second example work the same way as the first? 
Look at the condition of the loop. Is it not exactly the same condition just different ways of writing it?

The first example becomes false when there is nothing more to get. And then it stops.
But the second example never becomes false, it keeps filling the screen with results and never gets done. Endless loop.

Why does the examples behave differently and not exactly the same?

```
//First ex
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
print_r($rows);
}



//second ex
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
while ($rows) {
print_r($rows);
}
```

Comment: in the second loop `$rows` is assigned to `mysqli_fetch_assoc` once and never changes during the loop operation.

Comment: @Badiparmagi So in the second example $rows will ALWAYS have a value of a result and therefore always be true? And the first example gets false at some point because it wont be provided with a value anymore?

Comment: exactly! each iteration will set a new value to `$rows` in the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//First ex
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
print_r($rows);
}
```

This is getting executed at each iteration so putting next value inside `$row` at each iteration.

```
//second ex
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
while ($rows) {
print_r($rows);
}
```

In above code you are putting only first iteration value to `$row`. `$row` is not getting updated at each iteration. So this will run forever.

**Conclusion :**

> Each time you call `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)` it gives next row.

In first example, $row is having next row at each iteration by calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)` again and again on every iteration.

Whereas in second example `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)` is getting called only once. So your `$row` will have value every time you run while so it will run for infinite time.

Comment: So in the second example $rows will always contain a value of that first iteration, and therefore always be true in the whileloop condition and never stops the loop?
But in the first example the condition will be false at some point when there is no more rows to get, and therefore it stops?

Comment: exactly, you got it perfectly. It will stop when there is not more row to get.

Answer (score 0):

First one will fetching mysql data every loop. Because statement inside condition checking will run each checking. Second one is only run once.

Comment: second one actually never stops

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read how to write a good answer. read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/338114) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

the second while statement has no condition inside `while(condition){}` right now you have just declared a variable. hence it does not execute in the same manner as the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
//mysql users table
//id | nick | date
//1    | x1    | 2018-01-05
//2    | x2    | 2018-01-06
//3    | x3    | 2018-01-07

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    print_r($row);
}

//first loop call row one
//second loop  call row two
//third loop  call row  three

print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)); //print row one and mysql cursor jump to row two
print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)); //print row two and mysql cursor jump to row there
print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)); //print row there

//but mysqli_fetch_assoc bring one row not rows
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);


//row is null, no print and repeat
//row is null, no print and repeat
//row is null, no print and repeat
//row is null, no print and repeat
// ∞ :))
while ($row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```